# How to plot dot plot in r with a point representing the mean and error bars

Tags: r

I have a data set with a continuous variable (column named PI) and 3 categories (column named Size). I want to plot a dot plot for all PI values for each category and another point representing the mean and a SE error bar. Something which looks a bit like this from this Ross et al paper:

[image]

This is what I have so far (I have all of my points and my mean point plotted) but it isn't looking like the picture from the paper

```
p<-ggplot(Index,aes(x=Size,y=PI)) + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',stackdir='center',dotsize=0.5)
p

p + stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",shape=18,size=3,colour=c("red","blue","green"))

#to add SE bars
p + stat summary(fun.data=mean_sdl,fun.args=list(multi=1),geom="pointrange",colour="red")
p + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult=1), 
                 geom="pointrange", color="red")

    library(ggplot2)
`library(Hmisc)`

library(gplots)

library(dplyr)
plot_data<-Index %>%
  group_by(Size) %>%  
  summarise(mean=mean(PI),sd=sd(PI))  
m<-plot_data$mean
s<-plot_data$sd
plot(plot_data$Size,plot_data$mean,ylim=range(0:5),border="white",xlab="Body Size",ylab="Performance Index", ylim(c(1,3)))
points(jitter(as.numeric(Index$Size)),Index$PI,col=as.integer(Index$Size)+1,pch=19)
segments(x0=1:3,x1=1:3,y0=m-s,y1=m+s,lwd=2)
segments(x0=1:3-0.2,x1=1:3+0.2,y0=m,y1=m,lwd=2)
segments(x0=1:3-0.1,x1=1:3+0.1,y0=m+s,y1=m+s,lwd=2)
segments(x0=1:3-0.1,x1=1:3+0.1,y0=m-s,y1=m-s,lwd=2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help others help you, by providing a [mcve]. In particular, you should provide your data by editing your question to include the output of `dput(Index)`. If `Index` is a large dataframe, you may want to instead use the output of `dput(head(Index, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have your data, we'll use the pre-canned dataset `warpbreaks` to illustrate this

```
data("warpbreaks")
```

Your attempt was a decent first try

```
ggplot(warpbreaks, aes(x = tension, y = breaks)) +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', dotsize = 0.5) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1),
                 geom = "pointrange", colour = "red")
```

[image]

However, I think we can actually end up with a better outcome from "manually" doing it using base graphics

```
library(dplyr)
plot_data <- warpbreaks %>%
    group_by(tension) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(breaks), sd = sd(breaks))
m <- plot_data$mean
s <- plot_data$sd
plot(plot_data$tension, plot_data$mean, ylim = range(warpbreaks$breaks),
     border = "white", xlab = "Tension", ylab = "Breaks")
points(jitter(as.numeric(warpbreaks$tension)), warpbreaks$breaks,
       col = as.integer(warpbreaks$tension) + 1, pch = 19)
segments(x0 = 1:3, x1 = 1:3, y0 = m - s, y1 = m + s, lwd = 2)
segments(x0 = 1:3 - 0.2, x1 = 1:3 + 0.2, y0 = m, y1 = m, lwd = 2)
segments(x0 = 1:3 - 0.1, x1 = 1:3 + 0.1, y0 = m + s, y1 = m + s, lwd = 2)
segments(x0 = 1:3 - 0.1, x1 = 1:3 + 0.1, y0 = m - s, y1 = m - s, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you so much! I've just run this on my data and it appears loads of my data points have vanished (I have 15 replicates per each category). I'm thinking maybe this is because I have 9 treatments in total (3 sizes and 3 diets) but I just want to plot the sizes and I think it's just plotting the average of the 3 diets for each size. Is there anyway I can get each replicate on there? Also are the error bars on it standard error or standard deviation? thanks so much !!

Comment: @Lizzie The bars indicate 1 standard deviation away from the mean, as that's what the Figure 5 caption from Ross et al (2018), shown in your question, indicates they use ([link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/eva.12740)). It sounds like you need a second grouping variable, but could be hard to say without at least a view of (1) your data and (2) the figure the code is producing for you now. You can edit your question to include those things, maybe then I can update the answer. You'll also want to include the exact modified code you used (i.e. how you changed data names, etc.))

Comment: I can't upload my data column as I can't work out how but I have 4 columns:
Body Size (3 categories), Generation (3 catergories), Replicate (5 reps per treatment e.g. small body and generation 1 and PI (continuous)